# remove amd drivers installed with Automated installer

Tags: installation, drivers, ati, fglrx

I have installed latest beta 14.1 amd drivers `amd-driver-installer-13.35.1005-x86.x86_64.run` with the automated installer and now I can't remove them.
I tried: `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*` but it does not work because fglrx is not installed.

How can I remove those drivers?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer should have created an uninstaller script, so try to call it like this:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
```

Or check the /usr/share/ati or radeon for any uninstaller script.

When you finish, don't forget to install or reinstall the open-source drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```